# Raspberry Pi connected to wifi and a sensor on ethernet cable. Can't communicate with sensor

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi which is connected to wifi, and on it's ethernet port connected to some kind of sensor.
In the manual of the sensor it says that it has a specific ip adress which it can be contacted on.

But I am not able to ping this address from the pi.
I do, however, see the packages sent from it with tcpdump on the broadcast address. Packages are going from 192.168.1.20 to 192.168.1.255, so I can get them by listening to the broadcast address.

But how can I get them directly from the sensor on it's ip?
When I run ifconfig, I see under eth0 that it has another ip address and mask. Is this the problem? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must first change IP address on your Pi to same subnet and mask what your sensor has. Then you should be able to communicate with your sensor.
Then you should change IP address of sensor to subnet and mask like your Wifi, change RPi address back and than you should be able to see sensor from wifi too.

Comment: My wifi is already on the same subnet and mask as the sensor. But I guess the eth0 also has to be on this specific subnet and mask then? And I can change this by just setting a static ip for eth0 with correct subnet and mask? Correct?